# Saving pandas dataframe as csv and overwrite existing file

Tags: python, pandas, loops, csv, overwrite

I have always two dataframes which come from different directories with the same last four digits in their names. The filepaths are:

```
dir1 = "path/to/files1/"
dir2 = "path/to/files2/"
```

Then I use a loop to load and concatenate the dataframes which belong together to dataframe `df`.

```
# For each file in the first directory
for i in os.listdir(dir1):
    # For each file in the second directory
    for j in os.listdir(dir2):
        # If the last 4 digits of filename match (ignoring file extension)
        if i[-8:-4] == j[-8:-4]:
            # Load CSVs into pandas
            print(i[-12:-4] + ' CPU Analysis')
            print('\n')
            df1 = pd.read_csv(dir1 + i,delimiter=',')
            
            df2 = pd.read_csv(dir2 + j,delimiter=';')
            
            df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

What I now want to do is to store `df` in `dir1` using the same filename as before, i.e. I want to overwrite the existing file in `dir1` and save as csv.

So, I think I should use something like this at the end of the loop:

```
df.to_csv(dir1, i[:-4])
```

But I am not sure about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think here is possible join values by `+`:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
df.to_csv(dir1 + i[:-4] + '.csv', index=False)
```

Or use `f-string`s:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
df.to_csv(f'{dir1}{i[:-4]}.csv', index=False)
```

But if need original extension use same path like for reading file:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
df.to_csv(dir1 + i, index=False)
```

---

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
df.to_csv(f'{dir1}{i}', index=False)
```